# How to use javascript alert() in .jsp file?

Tags: database, forms, jsp, authentication, alert

I wrote a login form: First, you enter your email and password, then there's a checking to check your spelling of email and password. After that, the program runs to .jsp file to check if the user exists. If it exists, it sends the user/ admin to the homepage, else, it returns the guest to the login form. I want to add an alert says "Welcome user/admin" or "User doesn't exist". I tried this:

```
 if (session.getAttribute("Status")==("admin"))
    {
        alert("Welcome admin!");
        response.sendRedirect ("newindex.jsp");
    }
    else if (session.getAttribute("Status")==("user"))
    {
        alert("Welcome user!");
        response.sendRedirect ("newindex.jsp");
    }   
    else
    {
        alert("user doesn't exist");
        response.sendRedirect ("form2.html");
    }
```

How can I alert those messeges?

Answer (score 1):

You should write something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Form has been submitted");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in the js file that print to the console and call it from the jsp -

```
<% if (session.getAttribute("Status")==("admin")) { %>
    <% printToConsloe("your message") %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use scriptlet tags in jsp

```
<%
if (session.getAttribute("Status")==("admin"))
{ %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Your message");
  </script><%
  response.sendRedirect ("newindex.jsp");

}
%>
```